# probability of having 2 boys given at least 1 is a boy

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am in 12th grade and I can't really understand a question in conditional probability.
The question states

> There is a family with 2 children either boys or girls where both are equally likely. Given that there is at least 1 boy find the probability of having 2 boys.

If we take the 2 cases, in the first case if there is 1 boy does it mean that there are 1 boy and 1 girl? Or does it mean that we have 1 boy and the 2nd may or may not be a boy?

Comment: Without any information you have $BB, BG, GB, GG$. But with the information given that there is at least one boy, your space reduces to $BB, BG, GB$.

Comment: I was thinking if we already have a boy why can't the 2nd one be a boy too? By your logic if we were given 1 boy instead of atleast 1 boy wouldn't your answer be 0?

Comment: it's a famous probability problem read up on it:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#:~:text=The%20chance%20the%20other%20child,is%201427%2C%20about%200.52.

Comment: Well... is the boy born on a Tuesday? Because that may change everything...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Information_about_the_child

Comment: Hey, sorry for the ambiguity, but I quoted the question word for word given by my teacher

Comment: Originally there are 4 equiprobable possibilities: BB,BG,GB,GG. Under the condition one of them falls away and you are left with: BB,BG,GB. However the equiprobability of them is not affected.

Comment: Darth jedi: The comment by @RomainS refers to an interesting wrinkle that affects the probabilities in a more counterintuitive way (at least to some people's way of thinking it does).

Comment: I did not mean to confuse the situation any more, just point to some related interesting probability conundrum, as @BrianTung mentioned. Sorry for the confusion, disregard what I said if you're simply interested in your answer!

Comment: No problem guys, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RomainS: No, I didn't mean to criticize: I find that particular wrinkle quite interesting!

Comment: @RomainS I checked the Wikipedia article you linked and that has 3 answers given: a third, a half, and two-thirds. that just confuses me more. which answer is right among them?

Comment: @Darthjedi it depends precisely on the amount of information you are given... In your case, the answer by Sunny is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your confusion. Always write down the total sample space and sample space under condition. This is a question of conditional probability. The total sample space in this case is $\lbrace B, B \rbrace$, $\lbrace B, G \rbrace$, $\lbrace G, B \rbrace$,  $\lbrace G, G \rbrace$ each case with equal probability $1/4$.  When it says that there is "atleast one boy". Then your conditional sample space shrinks to  $\lbrace B, B \rbrace$, $\lbrace B, G \rbrace$, $\lbrace G, B \rbrace$,. Now  is asking the probability of having 2 boys, hence your favourable sample space is $\lbrace B, B \rbrace$. Hence the probability is = number of favourable sample space/ number of conditional sample space = 1/3.

Comment: That sample space doesn't have uniform probability on it ($\{B,G\}$ is more common than the other two), so you can't immediately conclude $\frac12$. And in fact, $\frac12$ is wrong.

Comment: yes you were right. I hope now is correct.

Comment: It's correct, but you should probably say that the four cases are *a priori* equally probable, and perhaps say a few words about why that is.

Answer (score 1):

The question means that there is at least one boy, second maybe a boy or a girl. You need to give the probability that both children are boys.
Without the information that at least one is a boy we would have four possible events
BB, BG, GB, GG. The probability of having two boys (BB) would then be 1/4 as each of the events has the same probability. But now we know that GG is not possible so we have only 3 possibilities so the answer is 1/3.

In greater detail:
Since the birth of boy or girl has the same probability Births in each order is given by
P(BB)=0.5*0.5

P(BG)=0.5*0.5

P(GB)=0.5*0.5

P(GG)=0.5*0.5

Applying Bayes theorem P(BB|one is boy)=$\frac{P(BB)}{P(BB)+P(GB)+P(BG)}=1/3$